Will bad english grades in high school severely effect my chances of becoming a scientist
I have got bad grades in high school English (Ds and Cs) but if I'm interested in something and have a good idea of the writing style and subject I can write well enough. so I want to know how severely this will affect my scientific career

Perhaps, in the near future, you will be able to write flawless English (with the aid of a computer).

It’s too early to tell but work to improve. Sorry but this is off topic here

Being a successful scientist involves a very large amount of writing about things you are not interested in.

Well, bad spelling is more likely to affect your chances than to effect them.

Are you in university yet? Undergrad admissions is the last time that anyone will care about anything related to high school. (Although being able to write well will become an increasingly important skill, so maybe sign up for some technical writing courses if your troubles were with writing rather than, e.g., overanalyzing literature.)

High school grades are relevant to entry to university, so bad grades may make it difficult to gain entry to a degree program.  However, if you can get entry to a science degree (or related degree) program then you will have a substantial period of time to learn the skills needed to have a scientific career.  Your high school grades will become less and less relevant as new learning and course outcomes supplant your older grades.

...but if I'm interested in something and have a good idea of the writing style and subject I can write well enough.

No, you can't.  If you could write well enough for professional scientific practice then you would be getting As (with ease) in high school level English.  Take your skill deficiency seriously and work on it throughout university.

Writing is hard. Good, clear, precise writing is harder.

I wouldn't take high school grades (low or high) as an especially strong indicator of technical writing skill. It probably depends on the school, but my high school English classes involved a lot more than just writing, and the writing itself was of a rather artificial "high school essay" style rather than anything that would be useful for scientific writing. (The question itself suggests that the OP might be a big careless with punctuation, but other than that, it's not too bad. Which isn't to say they shouldn't work on improving their writing, but they'd need to do that in any case.)

No one will care about your high school grades after undergraduate admissions.
But, whatever caused you to get those poor grades will not be magically left behind and could easily carry over into your undergraduate career which will then carry on to the next steps to some extent.
So, don't focus backward on the grades themselves. Do focus forward on whatever you need to change in your learning or work style to perform better in the future.
